# Fitting a CycloTricity E kit to a Sirrus Elite

Tags: electric-power

The instructions are clear and accompanied by photographs of the procedures.
However in attempting to fit the motor wheel into the forks of the Sirrus I find that the motor spindle is wider than the existing wheel spindle and will not fit into the fork drop out.At this stage the instructions suggest filing the drop outs to fit which I am loath to do, as if I wish to revert to non electric the drop out will be too wide.
I am tempted to file the motor spindle to fit the fork, about 2mm of metal.
All suggestions welcomed.

Comment: It isn't clear if its a 9 mm dropout vs 10 mm dropout here versus a width of the hub issue. Given that the Sirrus Elite runs a carbon fork, I wouldn't try  any foolery as carbon doesn't have nice failure modes to begin with. If the kit doesn't fit, try a different kit?

Comment: I've heard that you should be careful when mounting hub motors to carbon forks because they can apply quite a bit of torque in ways the fork was not designed to handle.

Comment: Return the kit as unsuitable for your bike, for a full refund.   Given this question is 6 months old, can you please tell us how you got on, and what you did?  It is totally OK to answer your own question and accept it.... future internet searchers will thank you for the closure.